# Validar $_GET que no viene de un formulario

Tags: php

Cuando se envía información desde un formulario se valida para mayor seguridad con `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'`.
Pero qué pasa si el parámetro que se envía no está en un formulario y está en una tabla?

```
<td>{$lista[i]->cod}</td>
<td><a href="index.php?action=consultar&valor={$lista[i]->cod}">{$lista[i]->nom}</a></td>
```

En este caso recibo el parámetro con un `$_GET['valor']`
Toda la documentación que he encontrado sobre SQL Injection trata sobre parámetros enviados desde formularios.
Cómo puedo dar mayor seguridad o restringir el envío de parámetros desde una tabla?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay un error de comprensión en tu pregunta al afirmar:

> *Cuando se envía información desde un formulario se valida para mayor seguridad con `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'`. Pero qué pasa si
>   el parámetro que se envía no está en un formulario y está en una
>   tabla?*

Si se trata de seguridad **a nivel de base de datos**, obtener los datos con GET, POST, REQUEST, etc no aporta absolutamente nada a la seguridad.

¿Cóooomo?  ¿Y por qué dices eso?

Por un motivo muy simple, para consultar a la base de datos **hay que aplicar seguridad a otro nivel: en la forma en que pasas esos datos para las consultas**. En el pasado se hizo popular el mito de que limpiar los datos con ciertas funciones que tenían la pretensión de ser *mágicas* era una técnica eficaz. La experiencia demostró lo contrario, de hecho, en la red (sobre todo en el homólogo inglés de este sitio) hay demostraciones reales de que, aún sanitizando datos te puede colar una inyección SQL.

La solución más eficaz para protegerte en este caso es muy simple:

- (a) Obtener los datos (por POST, por GET, por REQUEST o como quieras en una variable). Algunos piensan que esto tiene riesgo. No tiene ninguno, porque esa variable no se va a imprimir en el documento, se va a usar solamente para consultar a la base de datos.
- (b) **Pasar el dato obtenido en (a) a la base de datos de una forma de segura, mediante el uso de consultas preparadas.** Este es el *quid*  de la cuestión. De nada sirve limpiar y relimpiar un dato si luego se lo pasas directamente a la base de datos.

En la práctica, los pasos (a) y (b) mencionados se parecerían a esto:

```
/*
   *Aquí usamos un operador ternario para comprobar 
   *que el dato está en el GET. Puedes usar la técnica que quieras
*/ 
$valor = ( empty ($_GET['valor'] ) ? NULL : $_GET['valor'];
if ($valor){
    $sql="SELECT columna FROM tabla WHERE columna=?";
    /*
       *1. Preparar $sql
       *2. Pasar por un método adecuado el dato obtenido en $valor
       *   Es ese método el que se va a encargar de neutralizar la inyección
       *   Dado que $valor no saldrá de ese ámbito, no hay ningún riesgo
       *   en como se obtenga
       *3. Ejecutar la consulta
       *4. Obtener los datos si fuera preciso
    */
}else{
    echo "No se pasaron datos en el GET";
}
```

El código de más arriba es seguro. Pero digamos que tú pasas a tu variable `$valor` por todos los centros de limpieza posible, la dejas en remojo tres o cuatro días, luego la lavas, la enjuagas, la vuelves a lavar...  O sea, la aplicas todas las funciones de sanitización habidas y por haber y luego la aplicas tres o cuatro funciones más de limpieza que te has inventado o que has encontrado en la red.

Y luego de todo eso cometes la estupidez (con todo respeto) de hacer algo así:

```
$sql="SELECT columna FROM tabla WHERE columna=$valor"; //El riesgo REAL es pasar $valor directamente
$stmt=$con->query($sql);
```

Toooodo el proceso de limpieza que hiciste antes puede que te sirva, o puede que no, porque como ya dije, hay pruebas de que se puede hacer una inyección SQL sin usar absolutamente ningún carácter de los que escapan las funciones de sanitización existentes.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Mencioné lo del **$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'** porque forma parte de los filtros para evitar __sql injection__. Entonces me di cuenta que al tomar el valor desde una tabla, no hay forma de utilizar algo similar. Leyendo tu respuesta veo que lo único que puedo hacer es utilizar sentencias preparadas, indistintamente que sea **$_GET** o **$_POST**. Eso me queda claro.

Comment: @Piropeator si fueras a usar [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) para protegerte de la inyección, (¿quizá?) tendría sentido lo que dices sobre POST. Pero, como ya dije, y [queda demostrado aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/5587982) y en otros sitios, hay situaciones (quizá algo oscuras, pero existen) en las que te pueden colar una inyección SQL aún escapando los caracteres.

Answer (score 2):

te recomiendo que utilices [Sentencias preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php) para prevenir **sqlinjection** al leer el `GET` en tu aplicación:

También puedes consultar la utilización del método `prepare` ya sea para `PDO` o `MySQLi` que te ayudará a resolver tu problema:

1. http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php
2. http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: aunque útil tu aporte, responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad; dale editar y añade lo relevante de cada uno aqui